# Transferring battery energy form phone to phone

Tags: battery-charging, android, java

Is there a way to transfer the battery energy form a phone to another phone? I've seen it be done by using a USB to microusb adapter + USB to microusb cable like show in this video. Can I create an app to do this wirelessly using the phones technology, I see that alot of phones today have the ability to be charged using a wireless charger, but can you also do this form a phones perspective to charge another phone? I've done some reaching but I have not found a solution for this yet.

Comment: Is there an actual valid electrical/electronic engineering question here? Wanting to know if an android or cellphone can do this is best found out by asking a supplier.

Comment: I think wireless charging uses magnetic induction rather than radio frequencies so I would say the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

Wireless charging circuits are (the ones I have seen so far) different for primary and secondary side.

You charger is the primary side and has a driver which has a control circuitry to regulate the power which is put into the wireless charging, based on what the secondary side (phone) can handle (some form of wireless communication).

The secondary side is composed of a circuit which is able to get the energy out of the coil and charge the battery with it, but usually does not contain any driving circuit to put energy back in the coil.

So from my knowledge it is currently unlikely that one phone can charge another, because both are designed as secondary sides.

But I'm not up to date what the Qi-standard (or others) says about this, as the standard mobile phone solutions ended up not being suitable for our products, so we went our own way there.

Comment: I understand, my questionnow would be  could one possibility use "the secondary side" circuit which is able to get the energy and reverse the energy using the battery in the phone as the "charger"  and programming the driver as an app on rhe phoneand regulate power to another circuit?

Comment: That is what I was trying to explain, no it is not possible. The circuit is not able to do that.